# How To Bind Interpolation Data To ngModel In angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

- I'm trying to subtract two values and bind it to `ngModel` I'm Getting Null Values While Sending Data To Post Request.

> [Please Check This Image It Contains My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOzr6.png)

- I used Two binding But The Value Is Not updating It showing Pending_amount as null value

  `<input type="number" matInput placeholder="Pending Amount [(ngModel)]='paymentmodel.pending_amount' [(value)]="paymentmodel.total_amount - paymentmodel.advance_amount" name="pendingamount">`
- For example: paymentmodel.total_amount = 10
  paymentmodel.advance_amount" = 5
  paymentmodel.pending_amount = 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!

When using two-way binding, the binding both sets the value and gets the value.

You should *not* also use the `value` property. Try removing it.

Are you setting `pending_amount` anywhere else (other than the `value` property)?

If not, try adding the following to your component:

```
get pending_amount(): number {
  return paymentmodel.total_amount - paymentmodel.advance_amount;
}
```

This calculates the amount and provides it in a local `pending_amount` property. NOTE: This is separate from the paymentmodel's `pending_amount` property.

Then change your binding as follows:

```
<input type="number" 
       matInput placeholder="Pending Amount 
       [(ngModel)]='pending_amount'
       name="pendingamount">
```

This then binds to the local value.

Does that work for you?

Comment: I was wondering if I can set ngModel in input tag itself instead of explicitly assigning in TS. I see your method working fine for me thanks.